# How to make a page not directly accessible in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm developing a web application using flask microframework.

I'd like to have a view that is accessible only when it is redirected from another view and not directly from users.

To make it more clear:

```
@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@app.route('/home', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def home():
#Some code
return redirect(url_for('inProgress', parameter)

@app.route('/path/<parameter>')
def inProgress(parameter):
return render_template(...)
```

The view inProgress should be accessible only when it's "called" from the home view.

Is it possible?

Comment: How do you plan to do that? Via checking the referrer, setting a cookie, or something else? You know all of those can be bypassed very easily if somebody really wants to view that page?

Comment: I'm asking because I don't know how do it nor if it's possible. As far as I know, cookies are cryptographically signed in Flask. Anything on the server side?

Comment: You can not - just do that - as http is a stateless protocol. Nobody knows when you 'hit' an url if you were referred or not, the `HTTP referer` can easily be spoffed. So you need som kind of state handling. Cookies sounds like a plan. But i am worried that you are designing your application this way in the first place..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you issue the redirect, set a flag in the session object.  The "inprogress" view should check that flag.  if it's set, groovy, render the page.  If it's not, then redirect them to another page (and flash a warning about trying to access that page, optionally).

Comment: So far I solved through various check on DB. If it unveals inefficient, I'll go for this solution.